# chatgpt api streaming asynchronously in gradio chatInterface

Tags: python, python-asyncio, openai-api, gradio

I want to make chatbot with chatgpt api and gradio. (asynchronously and streaming)

here is my code. it returns `ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <async_generator object chat_with_gpt at 0x7f0840170af0>` because of 'yield' function.
I want to send stream chunk outputs in real time to gradio interface. how can I do that?

```
async def chat_with_gpt(prompt):
    stream = await client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}],
        stream=True,
    )
    async for chunk in stream:
        yield chunk.choices[0].delta.content
```

`print(chunk.choices[0].delta.content)` works well, but yield doesn't work.

Comment: How try to iterate over it?

Comment: Please give the traceback showing the error.  Otherwise we don't know which line of code raised the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this! Thank you!

```
stream = await client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-4",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": input_text}],
        stream=True,
)
    partial_message = ""
    async for chunk in stream:
        if chunk.choices[0].delta.content is not None :
            partial_message = partial_message + chunk.choices[0].delta.content
            yield partial_message
```